# Trying to pull the source code off a website getting very odd results

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I know I'm doing it the correct way but I do not receive all the sites source code when I run the code.

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get('https://steemit.com')
source = driver.page_source
print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
```

All it pulls is

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

It wont pull any of the sites real code. I have never had this problem before so any info would be a big help.

Comment: Why are you using webdriver for this rather than just making a direct HTTP request with urllib or requests?

Comment: I tried but the source code I want to pull is done in javascript.

Comment: Do you want to save the page source or use it within the rest of the script?

Comment: I'm trying to pull the feed data and analyze it. so use it with the rest of the script.